# CSS property filter: invert(80%) not working with IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, css-filters

I have a div container as below:

HTML:

```
<div></div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 100px;
    width 200px;
    background-color: red;
    -webkit-filter: invert(80%);
    -moz-filter: invert(80%);
    -o-filter: invert(80%);
    -ms-filter: invert(80%);
}
```

But the inversion is not applying for the IE browser. Whereas it is working with with other browsers like chrome.

[JS Fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/2L7qq8nj/)

Comment: [caniuse filter](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invert filter not working on IE and safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35997521/invert-filter-not-working-on-ie-and-safari)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invert is not supported in IE

[caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=invert)

Comment: Care to suggest alternatives??

Answer (score -1):

try giving the background-color that may help

Comment: Your answer duplicates the content of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27597982/3744182) of [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2665913/chris) from 2014.