# Invert filter not working on IE and safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

I am not able to invert the color of image on IE and safari. I am creating a navigation coin of images. When a user clicks or hovers on an image it inverts color. But this does not work in IE and safari.

```js
function Prev()
{
$('.pressed').removeClass('pressed');

    $('#'+imgid)
        .toggleClass('pressed')
        .css('z-index',2);
  
}

function switchVisible() {
            if (document.getElementById('mapButtons')) {

                if (document.getElementById('mapButtons').style.display == 'none') {
                    document.getElementById('mapButtons').style.display = 'block';
                    document.getElementById('modelButtons').style.display = 'none';     
                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById('mapButtons').style.display = 'none';
                    document.getElementById('modelButtons').style.display = 'block';
     
                }
            }
}
function flip() {
    $('.side').toggleClass('rotated');
}
$(function() {
    $('area').mouseover(function() {
        var imgid=$(this).data('imgid');
        $('#demo').text("Mouseover for "+imgid);
        $('#'+imgid)
            .toggleClass('invert',true)
            .css('z-index',2);
    }).mouseout(function() {
        var imgid=$(this).data('imgid');
        $('#mi').text("Mouseout for "+imgid);
        $('#'+imgid)
            .toggleClass('invert',false)
            .css('z-index',1);
    }).click(function() {
    var imgid=$(this).data('imgid');
    $('#demo').text("click for "+imgid);

    $('.pressed').removeClass('pressed');

    $('#'+imgid)
        .toggleClass('pressed')
        .css('z-index',2);
});
});
```

```css
#container img {position: absolute;}

img.invert {
    filter: invert(100%);
    -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
    -moz-filter: invert(100%);
    -o-filter: invert(100%);
    -ms-filter: invert(100%);
}
img.pressed {
    filter: invert(100%);
    -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
    -moz-filter: invert(100%);
    -o-filter: invert(100%);
    -ms-filter: invert(100%);
}

.side {
 position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.5s;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 0.5s;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
    -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility:hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility:hidden;
    -o-backface-visibility:hidden;
    backface-visibility:hidden;
}
.side.rotated {
    -webkit-transform:rotateY(360deg);
    -moz-transform:rotateY(360deg);
    -ms-transform:rotateY(360deg);
    -o-transform:rotateY(360deg);
    transform:rotateY(360deg);
}
.back {
    -webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform:rotateY(180deg);
    -ms-transform:rotateY(180deg);
    -o-transform:rotateY(180deg);
    transform:rotateY(180deg);
}


#mapButtons { position:absolute;top:90%;}
#modelButtons {
 display: none;
  position:absolute;top:90%;
}
.block {
   width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
   -webkit-perspective:100%;
    -moz-perspective:100%;
    -ms-perspective:100%;
    -o-perspective:100%;
    perspective:100%;   
}


#flip-button {
    background: white;
    font-family:'open sans';
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #5b5b5b;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: 1em;
}

.prevButton img {
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.prevButton:hover img {
opacity: .5;
}

.nextButton img {
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.nextButton:hover img {
opacity: .3;
}
```

```html
<body>
<map name="map" id="id_1">

 <div="container">

    <div class="front side">
 <img src="leftovers_ch01.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9;z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="02"  src="http://i.imgur.com/fpqmClk.png" style='z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="03"  src="http://i.imgur.com/TfhyWZs.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="04"  src="http://i.imgur.com/mUKWK5P.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="05"  src="http://i.imgur.com/R1JhAT9.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="06"  src="http://i.imgur.com/yMGFR2V.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="07"  src="http://i.imgur.com/rpCnGxL.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="08"  src="http://i.imgur.com/FWRCUs4.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="09"  src="http://i.imgur.com/Aw3NhT9.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="10"  src="http://i.imgur.com/gWhUtyJ.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="11"  src="http://i.imgur.com/IIJqsxf.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="12"  src="http://i.imgur.com/a9UW5mj.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
</div>

   <area  data-imgid="12"  shape="poly" coords="173,223,176,222,183,224,185,217,190,199,193,192,198,187,193,176,158,132,126,92,132,93,123,79,101,97,81,123,66,149,57,170,50,194,48,211,136,217,131,225,149,225,149,221,152,221,156,215,158,208,159,197,167,189,170,179,173,177,169,171,190,176,192,187,190,190,182,198"
   />

   <area  data-imgid="11"  shape="poly" coords="173,229,181,229,184,243,192,256,201,265,201,271,179,309,174,302,125,375,106,361,88,342,71,319,59,295,52,270,48,252,47,243,65,240,61,248,147,234,147,236,150,234,150,238,154,234,154,239,156,235,159,246,165,262,175,275,185,284,195,270,184,259,177,249,174,237,173,229"
   />

   <area  data-imgid="10"  id="ch10" coords="208,268,220,272,234,272,249,266,253,272,235,280,223,280,214,279,215,274,202,283208,298,209,295,222,297,239,296,251,293,261,288,259,293,262,290,262,296,264,294,65,298,266,295,276,310,266,309,304,389,285,398,259,404,241,406,210,407,187,402,169,398,152,390,158,373,162,380,203,273,208,268"   
   />

   <area  data-imgid="09"  class="notbutton" id="ch09" class="hotspot" shape="poly" coords="252,265,255,266,256,271,267,262,275,249,279,233,296,234,291,255,282,270,272,280,268,283,274,284,270,286,274,288,271,290,275,291,272,292,328,359,319,359,331,374,349,360,366,342,381,321,392,299,400,276,404,257,407,240,318,235,323,227,278,227,272,231,269,244,262,256,252,265" 
   />

   <area  data-imgid="08"  class="notbutton" id="ch08" class="hotspot" shape="poly" coords="251,188,253,181,267,192,273,200,277,208,278,212,274,213,288,220,298,207,294,207,289,196,284,186,274,174,262,166,268,166,266,164,270,162,267,161,270,159,266,158,276,142,279,151,329,78,338,85,349,94,363,108,379,129,391,152,397,168,403,189,406,211,389,213,393,206,277,225,272,222,269,209,262,197,251,188" 
   />

   <area  data-imgid="07" class="notbutton" id="ch07" class="hotspot" shape="poly" coords="247,186,248,182,251,179,239,175,228,173,216,174,206,177,199,161,213,157,225,156,239,157,254,162,254,158,256,159,257,155,258,157,259,152,260,154,292,72,296,79,302,63,286,56,263,50,242,47,213,47,188,51,166,57,149,64,188,143,179,143,201,181,208,185,218,182,236,182,247,186" 
   />

   <area  data-imgid="06" class="notbutton" id="ch06_09" shape="poly" coords="156,234,156,226,154,222,154,226,150,223,150,226,147,224,148,227,130,227,135,220,47,213,31,223,16,212,15,226,16,236,16,243,33,254,48,243,66,240,61,248,148,233,147,236,151,234,151,237,153,234,154,239,156,234"   
   />

  <area  data-imgid="06"  class="notbutton" id="ch06_08" shape="poly" coords="173,230,173,227,180,224,184,228,180,230,173,230"   
  />   

  <area  data-imgid="06"  class="notbutton" id="ch06_07" shape="poly" coords="205,264,207,268,203,272,162,380,158,372,151,389,154,407,136,417,124,412,115,406,108,401,125,394,125,375,174,302,179,309,200,271,201,266,205,264"   
  />  

  <area  data-imgid="06"  class="notbutton" id="ch06_06" shape="poly" coords="261,288,260,291,263,290,262,295,264,293,264,297,266,295,275,309,266,309,305,389,321,397,319,415,330,412,341,405,347,400,347,379,330,374,318,359,328,359,272,292,274,291,271,289,275,288,269,287,273,284,267,284,261,288"   
   />  

   <area  data-imgid="06" class="notbutton" id="ch06_05" shape="poly" coords="249,264,249,268,253,273,256,271,254,266,249,264"   
  /> 

  <area  data-imgid="06"  class="notbutton"id="ch06_04" shape="poly" coords="271,227,273,223,277,225,393,206,388,214,407,211,420,200,436,210,438,218,438,229,437,242,422,231,406,240,318,235,323,227,277,227,274,230,271,227"   
   /> 

   <area  data-imgid="06" class="notbutton" id="ch06_03" shape="poly" coords="256,163,262,166,267,165,265,164,269,162,266,161,269,159,266,158,276,142,279,150,329,78,329,59,344,51,333,45,323,39,316,36,300,45,303,63,296,80,292,72,260,154,259,153,259,158,256,155,257,159,254,158,256,163"   
   /> 

   <area  data-imgid="06" class="notbutton" id="ch06_02" shape="poly" coords="248,189,247,183,251,180,253,181,252,186,248,189"   
   /> 

   <area  data-imgid="06" class="notbutton" id="ch06_01" shape="poly" coords="199,191,203,188,207,192,205,187,207,185,202,182,178,142,188,143,149,64,133,55,133,37,122,44,112,49,107,53,107,73,123,78,135,93,126,93,199,183,199,191"   
   /> 

   <area  data-imgid="05" class="notbutton" id="ch05_06" shape="poly" coords="16,212,31,223,47,214,50,189,55,169,62,152,70,136,81,120,92,107,105,93,118,82,123,79,107,73,107,54,91,65,73,83,57,101,45,119,36,137,27,158,20,183,17,202,16,212"   
   /> 

   <area  data-imgid="05" class="notbutton"id="ch05_05" shape="poly" coords="108,401,125,394,125,375,112,366,97,352,83,336,69,316,61,298,54,280,49,261,47,243,33,255,16,244,20,270,27,293,34,313,45,334,57,352,71,369,88,385,108,401"   
   /> 

   <area  data-imgid="05" class="notbutton" id="ch05_04" shape="poly" coords="305,389,321,398,319,415,290,427,265,433,237,436,208,436,181,432,159,426,136,417,154,407,151,391,171,399,192,404,213,407,236,407,261,404,280,399,296,393,305,389"   
   /> 

    <area  data-imgid="05" class="notbutton" id="ch05_03" shape="poly" coords="406,240,423,231,437,242,434,264,429,285,424,302,416,320,404,341,390,360,375,376,357,391,347,399,347,380,331,374,345,363,358,350,370,336,380,323,387,309,395,294,399,279,403,265,406,247,406,240"   
   /> 

    <area  data-imgid="05" class="notbutton"id="ch05_02" shape="poly" coords="329,77,328,58,344,52,363,66,383,85,396,101,410,123,421,144,428,164,433,182,436,199,436,210,420,200,406,211,404,191,398,169,390,149,380,131,365,110,352,97,339,86,329,77"   
   /> 

    <area  data-imgid="05" class="notbutton" id="ch05_01" shape="poly" coords="132,55,134,37,152,30,174,23,200,18,219,17,240,17,260,19,276,22,291,26,303,31,316,36,300,45,303,63,284,55,265,51,250,48,234,46,215,47,194,49,175,53,157,60,149,64,132,55"   
  /> 

   <area  data-imgid="05" class="notbutton" id="ch04_03" shape="poly" coords="195,270,185,284,174,273,166,263,160,251,157,240,156,226,158,211,163,195,174,180,177,177,174,175,191,176,192,191,188,189,178,203,173,219,173,233,177,248,185,261,195,270"   
   /> 

    <area  data-imgid="04" class="notbutton" id="ch04_02" shape="poly" coords="202,283,215,275,214,279,223,280,234,280,245,277,257,271,265,264,273,253,278,241,280,233,296,235,290,257,283,269,276,276,267,285,251,292,235,297,220,297,210,295,209,298,202,283"   
  /> 

    <area  data-imgid="04" class="notbutton" id="ch04_01" shape="poly" coords="206,177,216,174,231,173,247,177,257,183,266,191,273,201,278,212,274,213,288,220,297,207,294,208,289,196,282,184,271,172,260,165,245,159,230,156,214,157,199,161,206,177"   
   /> 

   <area  data-imgid="02" id="ch02" shape="poly" coords="214,234,216,246,228,241,238,246,240,233,248,227,239,219,237,207,226,212,216,208,215,219,205,227,214,234"   
   /> 

    <area  data-imgid="03" id="ch03" shape="poly" coords="181,226,189,227,181,229,182,237,186,247,192,256,199,262,203,266,207,261,206,267,213,270,222,272,232,272,242,269,250,266,247,262,251,266,259,259,265,251,269,242,272,234,272,227,267,227,272,226,271,218,269,209,264,201,257,193,250,188,247,191,247,187,239,182,226,181,214,183,207,186,205,187,208,194,203,188,196,193,189,201,184,211,181,221,181,226"   
   /> 
 </map>

<div class="back side">
<img id="image1" src="blbl.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9;' usemap="#map2" />
</div>
</div>

<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="mi"></p>
<p id="clicked"></p>

<div id = "mapButtons" >
<button class = "prevButton" type="button" onclick="Prev()"><img id="image" src="http://i.imgur.com/PjVnMY1.png"></button>
<button id="flip-button" class = "changeButton" type="button" onclick= "flip();switchVisible();"><img id="image" src="mapButton1.png"></button>
<button class = "nextButton" type="button" onclick=""><img id="image" src="http://i.imgur.com/sR3xfJl.png"></button>
</div> 

<div id = "modelButtons" >
<button class = "prevButton" type="button" onclick="Prev()"><img id="image" src="prevButton.png"></button>
<button id="flip-button" class = "changeButton" type="button" onclick= "flip(); switchVisible();"><img id="image" src="modelButton1.png"></button>
<button class = "nextButton" type="button" onclick=""><img id="image" src="nextButton.png"></button>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Do you know [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#search=filter)? there you can enter some html or css tags you want to use and it tells you what browsers support it. and yes, IE does not support it at all and safari only with prefix.

Comment: Is there any alternative for color inversion?

Comment: Have you thought about using Autoprefixer, https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer? It would probably have fixed the problem in safari. Also, in your question, it would be worth noting the browsers it does work in. This raises confidence your question is sensible.

Comment: @Obromios Can you help me figure out integrating this in my code? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28253442/internet-explorer-and-safari-mobile-css-filter-invert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `filter` property is an experimental feature and does not work on IE.

To do some color inversion on image, you can do a sprite with the two separate images and show them in CSS with `background-imag`e and `background-position` properties for example.

See [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp) with sprites examples

As it said :

> A web page with many images can take a long time to load and generates
>   multiple server requests.
>
> Using image sprites will reduce the number of server requests and save
>   bandwidth.

You can do a sprites with all your images and reversed images and then get the background-position CSS with [this website](http://www.spritecow.com/)

If it's still too slow, you can optimize this image on TinyPNG, see this link : 
https://tinypng.com/

Comment: I  dont want to use more images. That makes my web page slower. I want color inversion. I just have black and white image so that should be easy.

Comment: I've edited my answer. So basically, you can put all your images and reversed images into one and get the position with the website "spritecow" . Furthermore, you can reduce the size of the image with the website TinyPNG.

Comment: Can this be integrated in my code? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28253442/internet-explorer-and-safari-mobile-css-filter-invert

Comment: No, this code works with RGB values. So it take RGB values and gives you the opposite RGB code. 
If you want a cross browser solution, you can test what i've suggested to you :)

Comment: Can SVG help instead of sprite?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17873715/how-to-invert-a-white-image-to-black-using-svg-filters can this help?

Comment: You don't succeed with my solution?

Comment: I have used z-index and done a lot of overlapping of broken images . So was finding difficult to convert it to sprite.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35926038/image-map-on-which-if-hovered-invisible-image-shows-and-when-clicked-that-image i have tried this.